# Kafka and Zookeeper Scripts Not Found Using Docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-zookeeper

**Detail:** I'm trying to run [wurstmeister/kafka](https://hub.docker.com/r/wurstmeister/kafka/) and [wurstmeister/zookeeper](https://hub.docker.com/r/wurstmeister/zookeeper) image using docker-compose.yml file which is attached at the bottom of this post.

To test the containers, I have followed the [official site of kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/quickstart). It refers to some scripts like `bin/kafka-server-start.sh` that isn't available in the image. I have also tried to go through the containers using `docker exec -it zookeeper bash` and `docker exec -it kafka bash` and found zkServer.sh and some other scripts in the `/bin/` directory.

**Problem:** The problem is that I don't know how to use it, because the config/server.properties is available in the kafka container not zookeeper. So I'm not aware of the proper solution. Is it a good solution to download the scripts and put them in the host directory and copy them to the container?

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version:'2'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"

  kafka:
    build: .
    container_name: kafka
    links:
     - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_OPTS: -javaagent:/usr/app/jmx_prometheus_javaagent.jar=7071:/usr/app/prom-jmx-agent-config.yml
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM wurstmeister/kafka

ADD prom-jmx-agent-config.yml /usr/app/prom-jmx-agent-config.yml
ADD jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.10.jar /usr/app/jmx_prometheus_javaagent.jar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use `bin/kafka-server-start.sh` script. There is script called `start-kafka.sh` in `wurstmeister/kafka` image. Here is how I did it in one of my projects:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
zookeeper:
    container_name: zookeper
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper:3.4.6
    ports:
    - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    container_name: kafka
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: kafka.Dockerfile
    image: kafka-service
    ports:
        - "9092:9092"
```

**kafka.Dockerfile**

```
FROM wurstmeister/kafka:2.11-2.0.0
COPY wait-for-it.sh /wait-for-it.sh
RUN chmod +x /wait-for-it.sh
CMD ["/wait-for-it.sh", "zookeper:2181", "--", "start-kafka.sh"]
```

Here in dockerfile, I essentially say: "Wait for zookeeper, he has to be up first,then you can start, then after him, run `start-kafka.sh`". You can download wait-for-it.sh script here: https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/blob/master/wait-for-it.sh

**PS:** You can see the essential information of any image using the following command:

```
docker inspect <image-name>
```

Comment: would you please write the equivalent docker-compose.yml file of the commands found in [kafka official site](http://kafka.apache.org/quickstart)?

Comment: Take a look at edited answer. You are missing CMD part of the dockerfile.

Comment: how about image: kafka-service?

Comment: kafka-image is built from kafka.Dockerfile. I included dockerfile because I had to enrich that official kafka image with wait-for-it.sh script since official kafka image doesn't include that script. You can go without that script ( CMD ["start-kafka.sh"] ), but I dont know what will happen if kafka start before zookeper.

Comment: I don't understand what is your question. If the question is how to write python producer, I don't know that, I am not familiar with python. If you are asking how to start kafka, I already answered, if you don't understand, clarify which part you don't understand so I can help a little bit more. If you want to run console producer, you can look at step 4. here http://kafka.apache.org/quickstart

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195936/discussion-between-mostafa-ghadimi-and-spasoje).